# C++ Error: because the following virtual functions are pure within

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

I'm having trouble allocating an object in my class. It feels like I'm doing it right but it's not letting me run. I've looked it up but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong or different from all the others. I've commented out a bunch of stuff and yet it still won't run

rifle.h

```
#ifndef rifle_H
#define rifle_H

#include <QPainter>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QGraphicsScene>

#include <QTimer>
#include <QDialog>

class rifle : public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
    rifle();//(qreal dirx, qreal diry);
    //virtual ~rifle();
    void move();
protected:

private:
    //QPixmap shot;
    qreal m_Speed;
    qreal m_DirX;
    qreal m_DirY;
};

#endif // rifle_H
```

rifle.cpp

```
#include "rifle.h"

rifle::rifle() //qreal dirx, qreal diry
//    : m_Speed(5.0)
//    , m_DirX(dirx)
//    , m_DirY(diry)
{
    //shot.load(":/pic/rifle.png");
}

rifle::~rifle()
{

}


void rifle::move()
{
    setPos(x()+m_Speed*m_DirX, y()+m_Speed*m_DirY);
}
```

and here's where I'm doing the code

```
void Dialog::fire()
{
    qreal dirx = ui->graphicsView->m_FireTarget.x()-200.0;
    qreal diry = ui->graphicsView->m_FireTarget.y()-200.0;

    qreal length = sqrt(dirx*dirx+diry*diry);
    if (length!=0)
    {
        // normalized direction vector
        qreal invLength= 1.0/length;
        dirx *= invLength;
        diry *= invLength;

        // creating an angle perturbation of +/- 3°
        qreal alphaPerturbation = static_cast<qreal>(qrand()%6-3) * M_PI / 180.0;
        qreal xPerturbation = cos(alphaPerturbation);
        qreal yPerturbation = sin(alphaPerturbation);
        // cos(a+b)=...
        dirx = dirx*xPerturbation - diry*yPerturbation;
        // sin(a+b)=...
        diry = diry*xPerturbation + dirx*yPerturbation;

        /*rifle**/ circle = new rifle(dirx, diry);
        scene->addItem(circle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the compiler told you which pure virtual functions are missing. Implement them. Simple as that.

Comment: It doesn't say any pure virtual functions

Comment: You're confused. When an error message says _"...the following virtual functions are..."_ it's _followed_ by a list of virtual functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html

> To write your own graphics item, you first create a subclass of
>   QGraphicsItem, and then start by **implementing its two pure virtual
>   public functions: boundingRect()**, which returns an estimate of the
>   area painted by the item, **and paint()**, which implements the actual
>   painting.

You must override these functions in `rifle` as they are pure virtual functions in the base class.